# Mark transaction as rollback-only in a MessageDrivenBean without retry the message

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, transactions, message-queue

I have the following MessageDrivenBean:

```
@MessageDriven(mappedName = "jms/...", activationConfig = {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "endpointExceptionRedeliveryAttempts", propertyValue = "5"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "endpointExceptionRedeliveryInterval", propertyValue = "1000")
})
public class MyMessageListener implements MessageListener {

    @Resource
    private MessageDrivenContext context;

    @Override
    @TransactionAttribute(REQUIRED)
    public void onMessage(Message message) {            
    }
}
```

Inside the `onMessage` method, I do some processing which is not important here. In certain situations, I want to give up on the processing. In that situations I want to mark the transaction as rollback-only and don't want to retry the processing.

At least on Glassfish 3.1.1, if I call `context.setRollbackOnly()` on the `MessageDrivenContext` and end the processing without throwing an exception, the message is redelivered infinitely in very, very short intervals. So that is no option for me.

If I throw a `RuntimeException` the message is redelivered as I have specified it. It is redelivered 5 times with 1 second interval. But in my case, I don't want to retry the processing at all.

If I simply end the processing without throwing any exception and without calling `context.setRollbackOnly()`, the transaction is commited, as one would expect. But I need to rollback the transaction because I may have already altered some JPA entities.

The question I have is: How can I mark the transaction as rollback-only without triggering a message redelivery?

Comment: What if you throw a `RuntimeException` and configure to not redeliver at all?

Comment: Because I also have cases in which I want to retry the processing. That's also the reason why a have explicitly specified the retry parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I see two options:

1. Annotate the bean with `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)`, use bean-managed transaction and no AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE (acknowledge the message explicitly in the MDB). Not an option if your MDB is a part of a larger XA transaction, you won't have a chance to influence the global transaction result.
2. Examine the `getJMSRedelivered()` flag on message and simply discard the redelivered message. The trouble here is, upon redelivery you don't know if it's a redelivery that you should ignore (you said in some cases you do want to retry processing) — you'd have to store temporarily (in a database, or cache) ids of messages that failed processing, so you know if you may ignore them safely.